# Modify immutable scala class field via reflection

Tags: java, scala, reflection

I need to modify public immutable field (with `val` qualifier) in an existing object imported from a scala library which I can not modify through source code. How can it be done with reflection functionality? There are ways to modify final field in java, so there should be one for scala as well, but I'm not sure about it.

```
final class Example(src : String) {
  lazy val internal = src
}
```

The internal field is AnyRef if it matters.

P.S. I understand that I'm craving for desperate measure.

Comment: Do you have the sources of this library? I don't mean to modify them, but just to see.

Comment: Of course I have it. http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/sxr/sbt/Defaults.scala.html#sbt.Defaults.configTasks

Comment: Ooops, the fact it's `lazy` can make the things more difficult (using Java reflection is almost not applicable)

Comment: Not much more difficult. You only need to make sure to access the val at least once before overwriting it (so that it is marked as initialized when we overwrite it, avoiding that the first access stores the initial value over our supposedly overwritten value).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Desperate measure you want, desperate measure youu get:

```
import scala.util._
def modifyField( obj: AnyRef, name: String, value: Any ) {
  def impl(clazz: Class[_] ) {
    Try(clazz.getDeclaredField(name)).toOption match {
      case Some(field) => 
        field.setAccessible(true)
        clazz.getMethod(name).invoke(obj) // force init in case it's a lazy val
        field.set(obj, value) // overwrite value
      case None => 
        if (clazz.getSuperclass != null) {
          impl(clazz.getSuperclass)
        }
    }
  }
  impl(obj.getClass)
}
```